# Animation xml for FAB to AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android, animation

I am trying to create an animation [like this one](http://gfycat.com/AnyEverlastingHairstreakbutterfly) to go from an fab to alert dialog. I am not sure how to define this animation whether it is via xml or an Animation Class. I am a big noob when it comes to defining animations so any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check this https://android-arsenal.com/tag/173

Comment: Holy Crap, that is amazing. Welp I just found something that I like, thanks!

Comment: nice to hear. I've already added this as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to spend much time to create a custom `xml` animation to your Floating Action Button, please check this additional FAB collections:

https://android-arsenal.com/tag/173

I think one of these looks pretty similar to your desired one.

You may also visit this tutorial: http://www.learn2crack.com/2015/10/android-floating-action-button-animations.html

Also check on StackOverflow:

- [Floating Action Button Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922191/floating-action-button-animation)
- [Grow Animation for Floating Action Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29951833/grow-animation-for-floating-action-button)

Hope it help

Comment: ok, maybe you can help me. I am using [this] (https://github.com/bowyer-app/FabTransitionLayout) library with the bottom sheet version. I keep getting a crash about RevealLinearLayout but that isn't in the main tutorial so I am not sure what is going on. Any Idea?

Comment: propably you need to add some more extra libs to build.gradle